# Does Will Ferrell use the same dog in his roles?

Tags: props, the-office, anchorman

In the scene from *The Office* where Will Ferrell is training Andy Bernard how to be a good salesman, he is holding a dog that looks very similar to Baxter from *Anchorman*.  Is Will Ferrell partial to this particular dog?

Comment: This is speculation, hence why I'm commenting, not answering. Maybe it's his personal dog.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I assume you are referring to this scene in the animal shelter:

[image: Scene of Andy and Deangelo in Dog]

He could be partial to that breed (the [Border Terrier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Border_Terrier)), but it is not the same dog:

Anchorman was made in 2004:

[image: Screenshot of Baxter from Anchorman]

That dog's real name is [*Peanut*](https://www.bustle.com/articles/30549-anchorman-turns-10-we-wonder-what-ever-happened-to-the-dog-who-plays-baxter), he died in 2010, according to the same source, and no mention of another relation to Will Ferrell is made. In *Anchorman 2* another dog was cast.

Season 7 of *The Office U.S.* was made in 2010 (it's hard to get a proper shot):

[image: Bad screenshot of Andy Bernard holding a dog in The Office U.S.]

The differences in size and colouring become obvious here.

Comment: Thank you.  I was looking for a clip of the show but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that Will Ferrell is partial to this sort of dog per say. I think it was done purposely as the show has tons of “hidden humor” for instance in the meeting before the booze cruise, in the conference room, Steve Carell is talking about titanic and jokingly Jim gave a smart answer followed by Pam saying “I think you mean the Hunt for Red October” referring to a  book by Tom Clancy that features John Krasinski on the cover.

Same dog though? No lol. As said above, poor little Baxter is in heaven.

Comment: I am unsure what you mean.  Can you please give me some more examples?